# Increment controller variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, increment, laravel

Having a controller like the following:

```
Class Upload extends Controller{
        private $up_count = 0;
        public function action_tmpupload()
        {
                if($this->up_count == 0)
                {
                        //empty a session variable
                }

                //some more coding to save data into a session variable

                $this->up_count++;
                return true;
        }
}
```

I keep wondering what am I doing wrong as the `$up_count` variable won't increase its value, it always stays 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: where do you display the value of up_count

Comment: I have a custom logging function that writes that value of `$up_count` among with other things, and it's always `0`

Comment: @JonathandeM. I've updated my question's code to be more accurate to my actual code

Comment: the code you posted is not the relevant part

Comment: Just for fun: Have you tried up_count = up_count + 1?

Comment: Seems like you just jumped into web programming. This expectation is common for non scripting language developers :)

Comment: @KGChristensen tried it, no effect

Comment: Is this a controller for Laravel or CodeIgniter, please describe your question properly before others can help you out.

Comment: @crynobone Laravel was developed based on CodeIgniter...

Comment: @w0rldart the founder used CI before creating Laravel, that doesn't mean it's based on CI.

Comment: let me rectify my answer... It has influences from CodeIgniter, and many other frameworks and even languages... but the controllers works the same as in any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you set the variable to 0.

Then next time your controller is run... You set the variable to 0 again!

You need to save the up_count variable in the users session - and retrieve the up_count from that same session